# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Worker Environment - HTTP POST Requests PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have setup SQS on my application server to send messages to my queue.
I'm able to send and get messages from my queue manually.

Now I've spun up the EB Worker Environment to get these messages automatically. It sends them as HTTP POST Request.

My question is how do I catch these messages. I'm using PHP. I have tried the below but no joy;

```
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');
$entityBody = stream_get_contents(STDIN);
```

The end goal is to get the message, decode it and use it to send an email.
FYI, I'm able to do this manually. I just need a way to automate the worker.

Comment: Can you tell happens when you try this? (i.e., what's the error, or what does -- or doesn't -- happen?)

Comment: Hi, nothing happens. Not able to echo, print_r() or anything. Messages get processed and deleted from the queue. My logic to process the messages doesn't work also. Thanks.

Comment: @moh_abk were you able to figure it out? I know it's been 7 years, hope you still remember the answer :)